# alert in javascript not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.getElementById("popup")) {
        window.alert("hi");
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="popup">dfdfs</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

i have a simple javascript which shows alert when the h1 id exits ,but i am not getting the alert message.code in jquery also can help.

Answer (score 3):

Put your `<script>` tag at the end of the `body`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="popup">dfdfs</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.getElementById("popup")) {
        window.alert("hi");
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because, you're executing the `script` before `document` is completely loaded, the element `#popup` is not found.

1. **Use DOMContentLoaded**

Use `DOMContentLoaded` to check if the `DOM` is completely loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
    if (document.getElementById("popup")) {
        window.alert("hi");
    }
});
</script>
```

2. **Using jQuery `ready`**

Using `jQuery`, you can use `ready` method to check if `DOM` is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#popup").length) {
        window.alert("hi");
    }
});
```

3. **Moving `script` to the end of `body`**

You can move your `script` to the **end** of `body`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="popup">dfdfs</h1>

    // Move it here
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.getElementById("popup")) {
        window.alert("hi");
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: DownVoter, waiting for comment here, why downvoted. Can something be improved

Comment: I hate it when people downvote and don't tell the reason

Answer (score 2):

Write your `script` after the element so that it runs after element is present. See the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <h1 id="popup">dfdfs</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.getElementById("popup")) {
        window.alert("hi");
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Plunkr for the same is: "http://plnkr.co/edit/0fznytLHtKNuZNqFjd5G?p=preview"

Answer (score 0):

Your script is above the `h1` element that you're trying to retrieve. Because of this, it is being run before the element actually exists.

Either move the script to the bottom of the page, or wrap it in a jQuery ready block. And consider moving it to an external file.

```
$(function() {
    if(document.getElementById("popup")) {
      window.alert("hi");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   try this easy way. no need of jquery. 

    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
 <h1 id="popup">dfdfs</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if(document.getElementById("popup")) {
      window.alert("hi");
    }
    </script>
 </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to use the `<script>` tags in `<body>` because it improves the performance by loading it quicker.

And then use

```
<body>
<script>
    $(function() {
        if(document.getElementById("popup")) {
          window.alert("hi");
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I know, I said, you missed `)` of it

Answer (score -1):

Below code gives you solution

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (document.getElementById("popup")) {
        window.alert("hi");
    }
});
```

Comment: stack overflow is not accepted i tired but not accepted